# Why do apache SSL certificate and key need to be in /etc/pki/tls/private/?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl-certificate

I have an Apache 2.2 web server running on CentOS 6.6. I have a certificate and key file that functions when the files are in this directory:

```
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/certs/mycert.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/mycert.key"
```

but it fails when the same files are in a different directory

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Apr  8 16:41 ssl

SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/mycert.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/mycert.key"
```

The apache error logs contain

```
[error] Init: Private key not found
```

SELinux is disabled. What would cause behavior like this?

---

UPDATE

The permissions for the files are the same in both directories:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2253 Apr  8 16:40 mycert.crt
-rw-------  1 root root 1675 Apr  8 16:40 mycert.key
```

Comment: permissions of the files? are they readable by the user httpd?

Comment: Have a closer look : your key file is only readable by root

Comment: It is absolutely correct that the key file is only readable by root. It is recommended in the Apache manual to do it like that (in fact they would even remove the writable permission for root).

Comment: The permissions for the ssl directory should be 700, and the certs/keys themselves should be 600.  Owned by root:root.

Comment: That is a convention. If you follow the conventions, you will have a happy life. If you don't, then you have to deal with the things that break, most of which aren't obvious. And for the love of all that is good stop disabling SELinux!

Comment: Check the following instructions. This can help you with certificate's paths, ownership, and permissions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html#ssl_certificate

Answer (score -1):

apache runs under apache user, not root, and you limited acces to root user only maybe? So try "chown apache /etc/ssl/mycert.key". It is very obvious, but you did not mention it, so just suggesting.

Comment: Apache runs as root initially and then drops privileges, so it can initially read the key file. It needs to do this to be able to bind to privileged ports such as 80 and 443.